# /var/lib/mysql shows files created by systemd-coredump for mysql volume

Tags: mysql, keycloak

`/var/lib/mysql` shows files created by `systemd-coredump`, while running `mysql 8.0.31` docker image. Is this an issue, not sure if the database is created properly in the first place?

```
volumes:
  - ./data/keycloak/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

> ```
> ls -l data/keycloak/mysql/
> total 87400
> -rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump   196608 Oct 19 17:25 '#ib_16384_0.dblwr'
> -rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  8585216 Oct 19 15:42 '#ib_16384_1.dblwr'
> drwxr-x--- 2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     4096 Oct 19 17:23 '#innodb_redo'
> drwxr-x--- 2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     4096 Oct 19 17:34 '#innodb_temp'
> -rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump       56 Oct 19 15:42  auto.cnf
> -rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  3026699 Oct 19 15:42  binlog.000001
> -rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump      180 Oct 19 15:48  binlog.000002
> -rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump      180 Oct 19 15:55  binlog.000003
> -rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump      180 Oct 19 15:58  binlog.000004
> -rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump      180 Oct 19 17:22  binlog.000005
> -rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump      180 Oct 19 17:34  binlog.000006
> -rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump       96 Oct 19 17:23  binlog.index
> -rw------- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     1676 Oct 19 15:42  ca-key.pem
> -rw-r--r-- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     1112 Oct 19 15:42  ca.pem
> -rw-r--r-- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     1112 Oct 19 15:42  client-cert.pem
> -rw------- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     1680 Oct 19 15:42  client-key.pem
> -rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     3540 Oct 19 17:34  ib_buffer_pool
> -rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 12582912 Oct 19 17:34  ibdata1
> drwxr-x--- 2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     4096 Oct 19 15:42  mysql
> -rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 31457280 Oct 19 17:23  mysql.ibd
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump       27 Oct 19 17:23  mysql.sock -> /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
> drwxr-x--- 2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     4096 Oct 19 15:42  performance_schema
> -rw------- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     1680 Oct 19 15:42  private_key.pem
> -rw-r--r-- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump      452 Oct 19 15:42  public_key.pem
> -rw-r--r-- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     1112 Oct 19 15:42  server-cert.pem
> -rw------- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     1676 Oct 19 15:42  server-key.pem
> drwxr-x--- 2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     4096 Oct 19 15:42  sso@002dkeycloak
> drwxr-x--- 2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     4096 Oct 19 15:42  sys
> -rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 16777216 Oct 19 17:25  undo_001
> -rw-r----- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 16777216 Oct 19 17:25  undo_002
> ```

Comment: Security, disk space, containment? I think you should mention some of your worries even when unclear.

Comment: There is sufficient disk space, so not sure what is causing this problem

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble, binlog.* can be deleted and also you need to configure logs size in mysql config, like

```
expire_logs_days=10
# from MySql 8
# binlog_expire_log_seconds=864000
max_binlog_size=1024M
```

You can set those parameters in docker-compose file in command parameter like

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: "my-mysql"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - mysql-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    command: ['--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password', '--binlog-row-event-max-size=1024M', '--binlog_expire_logs_seconds=864000']
```

and then re-build container.